# Google Cloud Platform with Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

This is more a support question than a technical question. But if you set-up the Google cloud hosting and you want to use Firebase. Is the cost included, or do you have to pay separate for Firebase?

Since Google announced the new Firebase I'm curious if it is included in the package, or is it separate from Google cloud hosting and you can just add it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Firebase is a different service than Google Cloud Platform(GCP).**

Firebase offers different pricing models.

Firebase uses resources from GCP and its pricing are also calculated as per GCP pricing in its "BLAZE" plan (pay as you go).

[Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

Firebase Storage uses Google Cloud Storage for storing images, videos and other large files.

> Firebase now uses the same underlying account system as GCP, which means you can use any GCP product with your Firebase app. For example, you can export raw analytics data from the new Firebase Analytics to Google BigQuery to help you surface advanced insights about your application and users.

New Firebase is now integrated with GCP. So you will now be able to use many services provided by GCP in firebase via integration.

[Firebase-and-Google-Cloud-better-together](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/05/Firebase-and-Google-Cloud-better-together.html)

So, if you think using firebase service plans are what fits for your product, its the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, had been searching for something like this. Probably searched in the wrong places

Comment: kindly can you answer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398705/google-cloud-platform-with-unity , i'm kind of stuck here. it is related to GCP