# Google Cloud Platform with Unity

Tags: java, c#, json, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was thinking of Google Cloud Platform (GCP) as the backend for Unity.

Can someone guide me to develop the GCP flow as authoritative, like if a request comes for
    deducting X gems to convert into the amount, then GCP get gems
    conversion rate from metadata, calculates the amount and increments amount in the user gamestate, also returns the new total balance as a callback
    [Remember: metadata/gamestate is saved in MongoDB (JSON)]

As i worked with AWS servers, so i want to know how to do it in GCP.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for here, but it would be best to write one specific question rather than what looks like two questions. Your first question looks like it's "How should I talk to my backend from Unity?" whereas your second question looks like it's "How should I implement my backend?" - those are very different concerns.

Comment: First, is how to integrate, while second is how to handle the specific case using GCP. It seems, you understand the question, so any help regarding that would be great :)
I searched a lot, but couldn't able to find relative material

Comment: Right, so you've got two questions you should be asking, each of which should be more detailed. At the moment the question is too broad (covering too much) and doesn't give enough detail to answer *either* part,.

Comment: Okay. You can refer to related article or blog post which explains it and covers these, even in any language as a backend, not only Java. it would also be great.

Comment: I can't at the moment, because you still haven't been specific enough. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ - and this should still be written as two separate questions.

Comment: Okay, you can leave the first question and can answer the second question

Comment: Please edit the question then, to give all the relevant information and only ask one thing. This will be my last comment unless the question is edited appropriately, as there's no point in me repeatedly asking you to improve the question and seeing no change.

Comment: question rephrased, now it is just asking one thing

Comment: All you've done is remove the Unity part. There's been *no* clarification of the remaining part whatsoever - including no indication of what you've already tried or what problems you've run into. Please read the link I gave earlier, and remember that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to run a server in the Google Cloud, you must remember that Unity is just a piece of software, with full access to C#. This means you can utilize the entirety of the .NET framework, Mono, .NET Core, or whatever other C# libraries to accomplish whatever task you wish.

The simplest method of getting a server running, as I've seen it done before, is to use NodeJS. NodeJS is pretty fast, and I had a friend have working multiplayer using NodeJS alone. This means that you can get a backend working without much effort, ASSUMING you do not have to also have a website pulling data off of this. [This would be where I'd start with that endeavour.](http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html)

If you want to stick to C#, there's another alternative called [ASP.Net Core](https://www.asp.net/core). Microsoft recently released something called .NET Core, which means that you can run .NET (sort of) code on Linux, Mac, etc. Either way, with C#, you're going to be needing to [make post requests](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) via Unity to the web server, and [process the returned JSON.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)

And finally, if you want to stick to C#, but not use ASP.Net core, you can always [just use sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx), or write your entire web server from scratch using a technology of your choice.

But, the most important thing you should take away from this is that Unity is capable of running C# code as software itself, outside of the game. All .NET code is accessible, for example, if .NET is installed on the machine. This means you could, theoretically, set it up with Mono, and use Mono instead. Unity is just an engine processing graphics, physics, and input entirely for you, with a layer that exposes C# scripting for you (where C# is an intermediate language).

Best of luck.

Comment: it is not related to GCP

Comment: GCP doesn't make your server side for you. It just hosts it. What I listed was the tools to create a server side, which you'd then host on GCP

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking "how to cloud host my game server" here which is an extremely complex question.

The process is exactly the same as you did with AWS in the google infrastructure.

Comment: so any tutorial related to it, or help regarding that would be helpful

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/getting-started/

Comment: so how to integrate it with Unity

Comment: I don't think you really understand what Google Cloud Platform really is. They don't magically make your game server out of thin air. You have to write that software, then host it through GCP

Comment: Yes, I know GCP don't do magically. that's why i asked for a tutorial how to do it

Comment: That's like asking "How do I write the code for my game server" ... it's too vague and out of scope for stack overflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your Unity backend logic for dealing with gems needs to be loaded onto Virtual Machines to run your gem conversion computations. The Google Cloud Platform provides different types of VM [compute options](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute/) to run your gem conversion logic on (e.g. App Engine and Compute Engine), which are accessible by calling URL [Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) from your Unity clients to communicate with via JSON.

These Virtual Machines can then connect to [databases](https://cloud.google.com/products/storage/) to store your gem and user gamestate information so that you may save user gaming records. It is recommended you read the [Google Cloud Game Server Reference Architecture](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/dedicated-server-gaming-solution/) guide, where it mentions using [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) as your scalable cloud database solution.

You might also want to check out [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to provide fast gaming updates to all of your Unity clients to do things like informing everyone of a user's new gem count.

Comment: have you found any tutorial which has step by step implementation of such related scenario of gems/currency

Comment: There are no tutorials with your exact gem/currency logic, but you can follow a [Hello World tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstarts-app-engine-standard) to setup your backend, then replace the Hello World logic with the gem/currency logic that you want to create.